# Navbar works in bootstrap v3.0 but not in v3.3.6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

The navbar does not work in the newer version of bootstrap(v3.3.6), the problem with it is the javascript part does not work like toggling to mobile view and dropdown and rest.

The code works wonderfully when I replace it with V3.0 of bootstrap but does not work when used with 3.3.6 (CDN and offline). I have cross checked for spelling and directory errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guru Prasad - Freelance</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css">
    <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar fixed-top">
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">Guru Prasad</a>
    </div> <!-- Navbar-Header -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar nav">
            <li class="active">Portfolio</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul> <!-- End Navbar-nav -->
    </div> <!-- End Navbar-collapse -->

</div> <!-- End Container -->
</div> <!-- End Navbar -->

<!-- //Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does _does not work_ actually mean? You need to provide details about the problem you are having.

Comment: You still haven't explained what about the **navbar** is not working, based on what you've provided they work the same in v3.0 and v3.3.6. Check the documentation because you're missing some elements that will cause issues in any release of v3 either way --> [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Comment: @vanburen The javascript part does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided (if you're doing something outside the default, you need to state that) I can't see how either could actually work.

You aren't attaching the *data-target* (`data-target="#mobile-collapse"`) attribute to the *navbar-collapse* div (`<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobile-collapse">`).

The same HTML applies to the following examples using **v3.0** and **v3.3.6**. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) Docs.

Working 3.0 Example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Guru Prasad</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobile-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Working 3.3.6 Example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Guru Prasad</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobile-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```